# How to trigger Prometheus to re-scrape and store time series data from log file?

Tags: prometheus

I'm new to monitoring servers and Prometheus and I have to maintain two servers (INT and PROD) with Prometheus 1.6.1 (server) and prometheus-node-exporter with Grafana.

From https://prometheus.io/docs/introduction/faq/

> How to feed logs into Prometheus?
>   Short answer: Don't! Use something like the ELK stack instead.
>
> Longer answer: Prometheus is a system to collect and process metrics, not an event logging system.

I'm confused, how does Prometheus collect data if not from application log file? Is this what prometheus-node-exporter is for? But https://prometheus.io/docs/guides/node-exporter/ states

> The Prometheus Node Exporter exposes a wide variety of hardware- and kernel-related metrics.

(and not on application level)

Since deployment of an webapplication update (Rails 4 to Rails 5) for some reason Prometheus (v1.6.1) stops scraping and storing time series data from application log file.

I updated on server INT Prometheus v1.6.1 to v1.8.0 (the last recent pre 2 version) and replaced the log file on server INT with the log file from PROD in an attempt to trigger Prometheus to re-scrape the imported log file but probably this is the wrong approach and what to do instead?